# how to use clion to compile python source code?

Tags: python-3.x, clion

I want to compile and debug CPython source code on Windows10. I have installed Clion on my computer. But when I open python source code with Clion, Clion can't jump code.

What can I do to use Clion to read python source code effectively?

PS: What I want to read is CPython source code which is written in C, but not py script written in Python.

Answer (score -3):

[Visit This Link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/python.html)

Simply Download the Python Plugin and enable it.
Make sure you have a Python Interpreter installed.

Comment: I want to read python source code, which are written in C. So I open the C code with Clion. Read python script in Clion is not my need.